# Can arraylist increase its size?

Tags: arraylist, size

In programming languages like Java and .NET, the Array-list data structure is supposed to manage its own size, growing as needed.

But is it possible to initialize the capacity to, say, 4000? If so, then why would we do it as we know it increases size on its own dynamically.

Comment: Please specify a programming language.

Comment: I just edited the question to specify the programming languages where this question is applicable, and clearly state the assumption that makes the question not obvious. Combined with the answer that already exists, I think this will be a useful question to keep on SO in the long term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize an Array List with initial capacity by :

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>(1000);
```

The need to initialize is for performance enhancement. This may help
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: thank you.....but can we check the size that we have added ? i used the same but size shown is 0

Comment: @rock the size will be 0 unless you add items to your list. Initializing the array with 1000 gives the list capacity to hold 1000 items without resizing. Internally there will be an array with 1000 null, but the API will not show that to us